# ngRepeat doesn't refresh rendered value

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having an issue with ngRepeat :

I want to display a list of students in two different ways. In the first one they are filtered by group, and in the second they are not filtered.
The whole display being quite complex, I use a ngInclude with a template to display each student. I can switch between view by changing `bClasseVue`, each switch being followed by a `$scope.$apply()`.

```
<div ng-if="currentCours.classesOfGroup !== undefined" 
     ng-show="bClassesVue">
    <div ng-repeat="group in currentCours.classesOfGroup">
        <br>
        <h2>Classe : [[group.name]]</h2>
        <div class="list-view">
            <div class="twelve cell" 
                 ng-repeat="eleve in group.eleves | orderBy:'lastName'" 
                 ng-include="'liste_eleves.html'">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list-view" ng-show="!bClassesVue">
    <div class="twelve cell" 
         ng-repeat="eleve in currentCours.eleves.all" 
         ng-include="'liste_eleves.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem happens when my list of students change (`currentCours` here). Instead of refreshing the ngRepeat, both lists concatenate, but only in the unfiltered view.

I tried adding some `$scope.$apply` in strategic places (and I synchronize my list for example) but it doesn't help.

EDIT : the function used to refresh `currentCours` in the controller. It's called when a "cours" is selected inside a menu.

```
$scope.selectCours = function (cours) {

    $scope.bClassesVue = false;
    $scope.currentCours = cours;
    $scope.currentCours.eleves.sync().then(() => {

         if ($scope.currentCours.classe.type_groupe === 1) {
             let _elevesByGroup = _.groupBy($scope.currentCours.eleves.all, function (oEleve) {
                  return oEleve.className;
              });
              $scope.currentCours.classesOfGroup = [];
              for(let group in _elevesByGroup) {
                  $scope.currentCours.classesOfGroup.push({
                       name: group,
                       eleves: _elevesByGroup[group]
                  });
               }
               $scope.bClassesVue = true;
          }
    });
    utils.safeApply($scope);
};
```

Comment: use curly brackets in here `<h2>Classe : {{group.name}}</h2>`

Comment: Share some more `controller`code ... You shouldn't be using `$apply()` imo...

Comment: @sachilaranawaka We are working on an homemade framework so we use brackets instead of curly.

Comment: @daan.desmedt The controller is quite complex, just a bunch of data synchronization functions, I'm not sure it would help. But if you want something specific maybe I could share that.

Comment: If you talk about a concatenated result - I suppose something is happening inside your controller ... But hard to help you out without the ability of checking your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround, but I still don't know why it didn't work, so if someone could write an explanation, I would be very thankful.

My solution was simply to open and close the template each time I switch between views.